# Moose: Array of Objects->loop through Attribute

Tags: arrays, perl, attributes, moose

I'm new to Perl Moose, and I'm trying to achieve this simple task. I have my Moose class "TestObject" defined:

```
package TestObject;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

has 'Identifier' => (is =>'ro',isa=>'Str');

around BUILDARGS => sub
{
    my $orig = shift;
    my $class = shift;

    if ( @_ == 1 && ! ref $_[0] ) {
        return $class->$orig(Identifier => $_[0]);
    }
    else {
        return $class->$orig(@_);
    }
};
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

In another script I'm trying to access the attribute "Identifier" directly from an array of "TestObjects":

```
use TestObject;
use experimental 'smartmatch';
my @aArray1=(TestObject->new("z003"),TestObject->new("t302"),TestObject->new("r002"));
my $sIdent="t302";
if($sIdent~~@aArray1->Identifier)
{
    print "Element with Identifier".$sIdent." found.";
}
```

This doesn't work. I could implement a workaround like this:

```
my @aIdent=();
foreach my $sObject(@aArray1)
{
    push(@aIdent,$sObject->Identifier);
}
if($sIdent~~@aIdent)
{
    print "Element with Identifier".$sIdent." found.";
}
```

but that doesn't seem to be the most elegant solution. What is the most elegant solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't name your class _Object_. That's really confusing!

Comment: I would say _don't use the smartmatch operator_. It's experimental and might change or get thrown out finally at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not do this with the smartmatch operator. It's experimental for a reason, and it might be removed from future Perl versions, or change the way it works, as it's done before.

Instead, this can be achieved with a simple [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

```
my @aArray1 = ( 
    TestObject->new("z003"), 
    TestObject->new("t302"),
    TestObject->new("r002"),
);

my $sIdent = "t302";
if ( grep { $_->Identifier eq $sIdent } @aArray1 ) {
    print "Element with Identifier" . $sIdent . " found.";
}
```

If you want that to be a bit shorter, you can also use [`first` from List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#first). This is a bit faster as it will stop looking after the first match.

```
use List::Util 'first';
my @aArray1 = ( 
    TestObject->new("z003"), 
    TestObject->new("t302"),
    TestObject->new("r002"),
);

my $sIdent = "t302";
if ( first { $_->Identifier eq $sIdent } @aArray1 ) {
    print "Element with Identifier" . $sIdent . " found.";
}
```

---

A few words of advice on your code:

- Do not ever name a class anything with *object*. It is going to confuse you, future you and the maintenance guy. If you do not understand the difference between *class* and *object*, read up on that please.
- Variable names and functions in Perl are always written in lower case by convention, and we use snake case. Camel case is reserved for package names.

Comment: "Do not ever name a class anything with object." One of my first jobs was working on the database generation component of a data modelling tool. Our database had tables called "database", "table" and "column". It was **very** confusing!

Comment: @simbabque: Thx for your answer. Yes, I know the difference between class and object, just wrote this code snippet for posting on stackoverflow. Could you help me out with a similar issue? I'm struggling to implement the grep syntax into a List::Compare Object: my $lc=List::Compare->new('-u',\@aIdentList,\@{(grep {$_->Identifier}@aArray1)});

Comment: @airborne just ask a new question for that please.

Comment: @airborne: *"I know the difference between class and object, just wrote this code snippet for posting on stackoverflow"* How are we so special that we deserve the confusing version?