# using List::Compare on an array of Moose Objects

Tags: arrays, perl, grep, moose

this question succeeds the following question: [Moose: Array of Objects->loop through Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115644/moose-array-of-objects-loop-through-attribute/46115851?noredirect=1#comment79195422_46115851)
I'm struggling to implement the grep syntax into a List::Compare Object:

```
my @aIdentList=("z003","t302","p032");
my $lc=List::Compare->new('-u',\@aIdentList,\@{(grep {$_->Identifier}@aArray1)});
my @unique=$lc->get_unique;
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I have one Array @ aIdentList with the identifiers and the other Array with the TestObject. I want to compare the identifiers in the first Array with the "Identifier" attributse in the second Array and get only the identifiers who are unique in @ aIdentList written in the @ unique Array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> \@{(grep {$_->Identifier}@aArray1)}
> ```

This part is weird. You are trying to dereference a list via `@{}`. That doesn't work.

The `grep` returns a list already. You do not need to use parenthesis `()` to construct a new list. Perl will ignore them. Then your `@{}` is simply wrong. You need a new array reference. That's `[]`. It will construct a new array ref from the list that `grep` returns. That's already enough to pass to `List::Compare->new`. The backslash `\` is only needed if you want to take a reference of something, but you now already have a reference.

But you actually do not want to `grep` here. You want to [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)!

This is what your code should look like.

```
List::Compare->new( '-u', \@aIdentList,  [ map { $_->Identifier } @aArray1 ] )
```

`grep` will filter out every element of the list you pass in where the block does not return a true value. Since all objects in `@aArray1` (typing this is horrible!) have an `Identifier` property, this will let all elements through. The second array ref arg to `new` will then be a list of objects. That's not what you want, because you'd be comparing apples to oranges.

Instead, you need to use `map`, which will pass the return value of the block for each element. It's like an inline `foreach` loop. Then your second list will be the actual identifiers of the objects, and not the objects themselves.